# how to concatenate the strings in two lists and then create a new list

Tags: python, list, concatenation

I have two lists and I want to concatenate them element-wise and added "or" after each new element.

```
a = ["new", "york"] 
b = ["spring", "summer", "autumn"]
```

Final output should be something like this:

```
I want to output something lke this: "new spring" or "new summer" or "new autumn" or "york spring" or "york summer" or "york autumn" or new spring or new summer or new autumn or york spring or york summer or york autumn
```

I tried:

```
for A in a:
    for B in b:
        AB = (A + ' ' + B + ' ' + "or")
```

but it was not close to what I want

Comment: Please [edit] to clarify the output, cause that's not exactly a valid list. `or` is an operator, not data. Maybe you actually want a string, like `'new spring or new summer or ...'`?

Comment: BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour], and [ask] if you want tips.

Answer (score 1):

Assumption: You want a list of all possible concatenations of an adjective in list `a` with a noun in list `b`, delimited by a space. You want this as a list `c`, not as a string delimited by `or` (for which you could simply use `" or ".join(c)`).

You want to "map" over a cartesian product. Python allows you to put multiple `for` parts in a list comprehension (equivalent to nesting `for` loops):

```py
c = [adjective + " " + noun for adjective in a for noun in b]
```

Or, to fix your solution:

```py
c = []
for A in a:
    for B in b:
        c.append(A + " " + B)
```

Comment: Also, `" or ".join(c)`

Comment: @MateenUlhaq I don't think that makes much sense. The OP didn't make clear that they want a string delimited with `or`; rather they apparently want a list of `or`ed strings, which doesn't make any sense. I assume they are just using `or` instead of `,`.

Comment: @Luatic Please either include any assumptions in the answer or ask for clarification before answering. (ref: [answer])

Comment: @wjandrea Indeed I should have made that assumption explicit. Edited.

Answer (score 1):

You can gather strings `[first list word] [second list word]` into a new list and then use `join` with separator `" or "` to create a final string

```
list_a = ["new", "york"] 
list_b = ["spring", "summer", "autumn"]

list_c = []
for a in list_a:
    for b in list_b:
        list_c.append(a + " " + b)

string_c = " or ".join(list_c)
print(string_c)
```

Output:

```
new spring or new summer or new autumn or york spring or york summer or york autumn
```

Comment: It's worth noting that a list comprehension would be cleaner: `list_c = [a+" "+b for a in list_a for b in list_b]`

Comment: You should also point out that you're assuming that's the output OP actually wants (which I think is reasonable).